# Why do Blender objects have a type?

Tags: objects, data-blocks

To the outside it appears at least superficially as if an object was not much more than it's location, rotation and scale values and the datablock handled the rest.

That's obviously not the case and you can only swap datablocks of the same type. Why is that? Why do objects even have a type? How do objects differ from each other when you ignore their datablocks?

Comment: Imho, at least to drive the properties in the panels... a camera, lamp or curve has not a mesh...? A linked camera can be set as active... etc.

Comment: @m.ardito That info could be taken from the datablock

Comment: I understand, but in that way even local objects could behave as you say... perhaps? Maybe linked objects have a type because even local objects have one.

Comment: `bpy.types.Object` has props common to all types. I'd imagine that setting the readonly `type` once an object is instanced, based on its data,  is an arbitrary but logical choice.  Swapping an object from an empty to a lamp to a mesh to a lattice ??? the mind boggles.

Comment: @batFINGER Swapping datablocks is in no way weirder than being able to turn any object into the active camera.

Comment: Moot point.:  doesn't turn the object into a camera, rather it uses the objects  -Z axis as if it were the camera.  The Z axis is an object property.

Comment: since this is gone back to all objects, not just linked, it seems it's a question for blender developers, perhaps: "why blender was not thought to use generic objects which can use any kind of datablock?".

Comment: @m.ardito it would be a nightmare.. imagine turning an armature object to a whatever after setting up a rig. There is an expectation that once a "blonk" always a "blonk".

Comment: @batFINGER I agree, but I was just suggesting HH that his question was more about blender internal developer's choices (and, done in a far past, and still "compatible"...)